# What's the difference between 'schemamigrate' and 'schemamigration' in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, database-schema, django-south, django-migrations

I'm fairly new to `Django` (1.6) and `South`, when googling [*"django south migration"*](http://is.gd/vZslbk), I came accross some [diagram mentioning the `schemamigrate` task](https://farm6.static.flickr.com/5124/5320564174_5bdafd7d21.jpg).

[image]

I'm only familiar with the `schemamigration` task.

So what's the difference between `schemamigrate` and `schemamigration` in Django?

Comment: It's pretty clear this is simply a mistake in this random diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`South` [does not provide `schemamigrate` command](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html). They meant [`schemamigration`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html?highlight=schemamigrate#schemamigration) instead.

---

[`schemamigration`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html?highlight=schemamigrate#schemamigration) command analyzes the models you have defined in `models.py` and the tables in the database, understands the difference and generates migration files.

[`migrate`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html?highlight=schemamigrate#migrate) applies these generated migrations to the database.

These command are usually used one by one:

- make changes to the models
- generate migrations with `schemamigration`
- apply migrations via `migrate`

FYI, [`South tutorial`](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#changing-the-model) has a relevant example.